# Listing data using find statement and join table

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following tables for my CakePHP app that allows friendships between users:

```
**Users**
id
username
password

**Profiles**
id
firstname
lastname
user_id

**Friends**
id
user_id_to
user_id_from
status
```

So basically a user has a profile and a user can be friends with another user and this is recorded in the database table called friends with a simple status of confirmed or not using either 0 or 1 (it's an int). So friends is the join between two users.

I'm trying to list the friends for a user so for example if I get a url like:

`/people/cameron/friends` it will list the friends for the user Cameron.

However I'm struggling with the find statement to pass the user and find them (notice I contain the profile data) and then list friends that are related to that user. Can anyone help?

These are the Friend, User and Profile models:

```
class Friend extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Friend';

    public $belongsTo = array('User');

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

}
```

User.php

```
   class User extends AppModel
    {
        public $name = 'User';

    public $hasOne = 'Profile';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Post',
        'Answer',
        'Friend' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id_to'
        )
    );

public $belongsTo = array(
        'Friend' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id_from'
        )
    );

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

        public function getFriends($username)
        {
        return $this->find('all',
        array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $username, 'Friend.status'=>1),
            'contain' => array('Friend' => array('User'))
        ));
        }
    }
```

Profile.php

```
class Profile extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Profile';

    public $belongsTo = 'User';

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

and this is my method for showing the friend list for a user:

```
public function index( $username )
{   
    $friends = $this->User->getFriends($username);

    $this->set('friends', $this->paginate());
}
```

I'm currently getting this error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.user_id_from' in 'on clause'
SQL Query: SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`status`, `User`.`code`, `User`.`lastlogin`, `Friend`.`id`, `Friend`.`user_id_from`, `Friend`.`user_id_to`, `Friend`.`datetime`, `Friend`.`status` FROM `db52704_favorr`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `db52704_favorr`.`friends` AS `Friend` ON (`User`.`user_id_from` = `Friend`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`username` = 'cameron' AND `Friend`.`status` = 1
```

It looks as though the app thinks the foreign keys are in the User table rather than the friend table even though they called within the Friend association... Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Any updates to this as I'm sure it's something simple that's just in the wrong place... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you specify foreign keys for $belongsTo, remember that the name you specify is the name of the field in the *current* table, not the other table.

So, for example, your $belongsTo references to `'foreignKey' => 'user_id_to'` should be in the **Friends model**, not the Users model.

Re-read Cake's docs, as it does get confusing (even after years of Cake apps, I still need to refresh when I start a new project): http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: But I'm saying the user belongs to a friend and has many friends so would have to be in the User model surely?

Comment: Check the link I posted; Cake's belongsTo / hasOne / hasMany can be unintuitive. The docs specify where the FKs are stored for each type. Here's a cut/paste from the docs:  `hasOne: the other model contains the foreign key; belongsTo: the current model contains the foreign key; hasMany: the other model contains the foreign key.` And so on. See the examples to better understand.

Comment: This still makes no sense! Can you post what should be in each model as I really don't get this.

Comment: I think what is really confusing me is that it feels like I have two foreign keys for the friend model because of user_id_from and user_id_to

Comment: Cake's allows for aliasing which allows you to specify different names for the associations when both associations are on the same table. See: http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/851/Multiple-relations-to-the-same-model

Answer (score 0):

Cake appears to be getting confused by those foreignKey assignments when constructing the join query.

you could try replacing each relation with the following to force the right join statement:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Friend' => array(
        'foreignKey' => null,
        'conditions' => array('Friend.user_id_to = User.id')
    )
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Friend' => array(
        'foreignKey' => null,
        'conditions' => array('Friend.user_id_from = User.id')
    )
);
```